# How do I retain the most recent commit after rebase

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, git-rebase

So currently my commit tree look something like this

```
      D <- newFeature
     /
A-B-C-E <- mainline
```

After I did these

```
git checkout newFeature
git rebase mainline
```

A merge conflict happened and the latest commit tree looks like

```
A-B-C-E <- newFeature
```

I really want to keep commit D, how do I not lose it and make the tree something like

```
A-B-C-E-D
```

Answer (score 0):

Git keeps logs of where refs have pointed, so after you've rebased, `newFeature@{1}` is where it was just before you rebased it. Abandoned commits aren't garbage-collected until they've been wholly unreachable from any ref for at least a couple weeks (there's arguably-excessive complexity in how Git picks and configures its gc-protection intervals, see the docs, but two weeks is the smallest safety interval before Git will regard an abandoned commit as safe to toss), you can get their id's by checking your reflogs and check them out or add a ref for them by id or reflog lookup or whatever works, `git tag newFeature{-before-rebase,@{1}}`

Answer (score 0):

In my case the steps are as following:

```
git checkout newFeature
git rebase mainline
```

Resolve all the conflict

```
git add .
git commit
```

I think the commit is not lost, it is just being hold. I am not able to use `git commit --amend` since it will be commit `E` that I am modifing.